# NoClassDefFoundError in org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53

Tags: aop, spring-boot

**NoClassDefFoundError in org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53**

I'm developing an AOP logger.  It works fine with a straight up Java class with a main() method but is failing when used in conjunction with Spring Boot.  The logging jar file is in both the bootclasspath and the class path. An exception is thrown even before I'm able to print out the class path.  Am I missing a configuration step to make Spring Boot happy?

The exception:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.co.brs.logging.aop.AopLogger
    at com.co.brs.restserver.RestApplication.main(RestApplication.java:73)
    ... 6 more
```

The command line:

```
/usr/java/latest/bin/java -Xbootclasspath/p:/usr/local/co/lib/logging-logger.jar -server -cp /usr/local/co/lib/logging-logger.jar:/usr/local/co/bin/../lib/restserver:/usr/local/co/lib/*:/usr/local/co/catalog/lib/*:/usr/local/co/lib/logging-logmanager/* -jar /usr/local/co/bin/../lib/restserver/rest-server.jar >> /usr/local/co/bin/../log/restserver.out 2>&1 &
```

The RestApplication.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"com.co.brs.restserver.component", "com.co.brs.restserver.service", "com.co.brs.restserver.web", "com.co.brs.restserver.doc"})
public class RestApplication {

    @Value("${keystore.file}") private String keystoreFile;
    @Value("${keystore.pass}") private String keystorePass;
    @Value("${keystore.type}") private String keystoreType;
    @Value("${secure.port}") private String securePort;

    /**
     * Start Spring boot Application
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ClassLoader loader = RestApplication.class.getClassLoader();  
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
        //Get the System Classloader
        ClassLoader sysClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

        //Get the URLs
        URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)sysClassLoader).getURLs();

        for(int i=0; i< urls.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(urls[i].getFile());
        }       
        SpringApplication restApp = new SpringApplication(RestApplication.class);
        restApp.setShowBanner(false);
        restApp.setDefaultProperties(new HashMap<String, Object>());
        ApplicationContext context = restApp.run(args);
        RestService restService = context.getBean(RestService.class);
        restApp.setRegisterShutdownHook(true);

        // Start component
        if (!restService.start()) {
            // Failed to start
            System.out.println("Failed to start - exiting\n");
            System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(context, new JobExecutionExitCodeGenerator()));
        }
        System.out.println("Rest Service is up and running");
    }
```

And the AOP Logger snippet:

```
pointcut logMethod():
    (execution(public * *(..)) && !execution(public * get*(..)) && !execution(public void set*(..)) 
            && !cflow(adviceexecution() && !execution(public com.co.brs.logging* *(..))));

before(): logMethod() {...}
```

The pom.xml file includes the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.co.brs.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>logging-logger</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I updated the point cut in the AOPLogger to ignore main() methods and got farther.

The point cut:

```
pointcut logMethod():
    (execution(public * *(..)) && !execution(public * get*(..)) && !execution(public void set*(..))  && !execution(public void main(..)) 
            && !cflow(adviceexecution() && !execution(public com.co.brs.logging* *(..))));
```

New output:  (The code is getting into the execution:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/runtime/reflect/Factory
    at com.co.brs.logging.CatalogHandler.ajc$preClinit(CatalogHandler.java:1)
    at com.co.brs.logging.CatalogHandler.<clinit>(CatalogHandler.java:1)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$5.run(LogManager.java:966)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.loadLoggerHandlers(LogManager.java:958)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.initializeGlobalHandlers(LogManager.java:1578)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$1500(LogManager.java:145)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.accessCheckedHandlers(LogManager.java:1667)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getHandlers(Logger.java:1776)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:169)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j.Log4JLoggingSystem.beforeInitialize(Log4JLoggingSystem.java:64)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:135)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:98)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:100)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.started(EventPublishingRunListener.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:276)
    at com.emc.brs.restserver.RestApplication.main(RestApplication.java:62)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Not 100% sure but Spring Boot packages everything inside the jar and has a custom class loader. I doubt that the -cp is even doing anything for a spring boot application.

Comment: I ran jar tvf on the rest-server.jar and it looks like the logging-logger.jar is included, but yeah, that could be a thing.

Answer (score 0):

I further updated the pointcut to only include the package for my product and now the code gets past the initial boot without a problem.  The final pointcut defines an intercept for my package, not simple getters and setters, not the logging package itself, not main() methods and not while already giving advice.

```
pointcut logMethod():
    (execution(public com.co.brs* *(..)) 
    && !execution(public * get*(..)) 
    && !execution(public void set*(..))  
    && !execution(public void main(..)) 
    && !cflow(adviceexecution() 
    && !execution(public com.co.brs.logging* *(..))));

before(): logMethod() 
{ ... }
```

Comment: I think you have a few mistakes in your own answer, see my answer. It is too complex for a simple comment so I wrote another answer.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you want to capture public method calls within a certain package instead of method calls returning types from that package, i.e. `execution(public * com.co.brs..*(..))` rather than `execution(public com.co.brs..* *(..))`. The same is true for the logging execution at the end, you also got that one wrong.

You can also further refine your pointcut, e.g. by

- using a construct like `com.co.brs..*` instead of `com.co.brs*` to explicitly denote that you mean package `com.co.brs` and all its subpackages,
- omitting the `public` modifiers on subsequent pointcuts chained together via `&&` because the first pointcut already limits executions to public ones.
- You also do not need the outermost parentheses enclosing everything.

```java
pointcut logMethod():
    execution(public * com.co.brs..*(..)) &&
    !execution(* get*(..)) &&
    !execution(void set*(..)) &&
    !execution(void main(..)) &&
    !cflow(adviceexecution()) &&
    !execution(* com.co.brs.logging..*(..));
```

Please also note that `!cflow(adviceexecution())` also excludes execution of other advice from other aspects. If this is what you want it is fine. If not, you should rather use something like `!within(MyAdvice)` instead.